# MySQL: Rows where criteria does NOT EXIST

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select the User_ID of all rows which do NOT have 'bar' in the Meta column.

```
ID   User_ID   Meta
1    User1     foo
2    User2     foo
3    User2     bar
4    User3     foo
5    User4     foo
6    User4     bar
```

However, I can't get er to work. I can get the User_Id that DO have 'bar' in 10 different ways, but can't figure this one out. Neither of these work:

```
SELECT User_ID
FROM t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM t
                WHERE t.meta = 'bar') )
```

The above yields all Users, with and without 'bar' in the Meta column.

```
SELECT User_ID
FROM t
WHERE t.meta <> 'bar'
```

The above yields all Users, with and without 'bar' in the Meta column.

Desired output should be:

```
User1
User3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to do it:

```
SELECT A.USER_ID
FROM T A
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT NULL FROM T B WHERE A.USER_ID=B.USER_ID AND B.META='bar');
```

See it run on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d8a72e/1).

Comment: Perfect! That is exactly what I needed. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could try a NOT IN the result for User_ID that have t.meta='bar'

```
SELECT distinct User_ID
FROM t
WHERE User_ID NOT IN  (
            SELECT User_ID  
            FROM t
            WHERE trim(t.meta) = 'bar')
```

and if you need  distinct result use distinct clause

Comment: Thanks, tried that and that is giving me all users both with and without.

Comment: impossible  .. check better and use NOT IN

Comment: anyway answer  updated  with a suggestion for distinct

Comment: just for test show me the result only for SELECT User_ID  
            FROM t
            WHERE t.meta = 'bar'   .. and let me know the User_id you obtain  .....(should return 2,4)  and add  also the real query you are using ..

Comment: The test does show me only the ones you'd expect (2,4).

Comment: this mean that  your data are not as in your sample  ...  check really for bar  in t.meta ..  eg. using trim(t.meta)  .. answer  updated ..  with trim .

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT User_ID FROM t WHERE NOT Meta = 'bar';
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you correctly

maybe this query may help you

```
SELECT u.user_id
FROM users u
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM users v
  WHERE v.meta = 'bar'
  AND u.user_id = v.user_id
)
```